# How to provide secret-id for AppRole in Spring

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, vault

I am using HashiCorp Vault in conjunction with the `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-vault-config` library for Spring and I need some help.

I'd like to use the `AppRole` auth method, and I'd like to know what's the best way to provide the `role-id` and `secret-id` for a Spring app which runs in Docker. The Spring documentation does hardcoding into the application properties, which is not an option for me.

```yaml
spring.cloud.vault:
    authentication: APPROLE
    app-role:
        role-id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        secret-id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
        role: my-role
        app-role-path: approle
```

With the TOKEN method, it's possible to provide the token as a file named `.vault-token` in the classpath. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find out if this is possible too for the secret-id when using AppRole. That would be my preferred approach, as I don't have a good method yet to provide it dynamically.